# Collect the stop-the-world duration in a concurrent GC (G1)

Tags: java, garbage-collection, g1gc

So currently Im using `ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans()` but the young GC in G1 only includes 2 steps that are actually STW.

From the duration (and I might be wrong here) I gather the time reported is for the entire young GC (including the concurrent phases), can I somehow get just the STW duration?